# Rails join - find records that don't have a join matching a specific condiiton

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-2

In my Rails 2.2.2 app I have two tables/models joined like so:

```
School
  has_many :licenses, :as => :licensable

License
  belongs_to :licensable, :polymorphic => true
  #important fields for this question:
  #start_date: datetime
  #end_date: datetime
```

If i want to search for all schools with a current license, it's simple enough:

```
licensed_schools = School.find(:all, :include => [:licenses], :conditions => ["licenses.start_date < ? and licenses.end_date > ?", Time.now, Time.now])
```

This finds me all the schools that have a valid license in the join table.  So far so good.

However, if i want to find all the schools that don't have a valid license, it's more difficult (so far):  for example if i do

```
unlicensed_schools = = School.find(:all, :include => [:licenses], :conditions => ["licenses.id is null or licenses.start_date > ? or licenses.end_date < ?", Time.now, Time.now]
```

then i get back any school that a) don't have any licenses at all (fine) or b) has at least one invalid license, including schools which have an old (invalid) license AND a new (valid) license.

In other words it's returning all schools that either have no license OR have one or more invalid licenses (regardless of whether they have a valid license as well).  It should be returning all schools that have 0 valid licenses.

I can't quite figure out how to do this.  Any help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arel for this using `exists`:

```
licenses = License.arel_table    
School.where(
  License.where(
    licenses[:school_id].eq(School.arel_table[:id]).
    and(licenses[:start_date].gte(Time.now)).
    and(licenses[:end_date].lte(Time.now))).exists)
```

Alternatively you can build a custom LEFT JOIN and check for NULLs:

```
licenses = License.arel_table
schools = School.arel_table
custom_join = schools.join(licenses, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).
                on(licenses[:school_id].eq(schools[:id].
                   and(licenses[:start_date].gte(Time.now)).
                   and(licenses[:end_date].lte(Time.now))).join_sources
School.joins(custom_join).where(licenses: {id: nil})
```

You can also skip Arel completely and build the LEFT JOIN by hand:

```
School.joins("LEFT JOIN licenses ON licenses.school_id = schools.id AND '#{Time.now.to_s(:db)}' BETWEEN licenses.start_date AND licenses.end_date").
       where(licenses: {id: nil})
```

A LEFT JOIN will typically be less performant than EXISTS, although you might find it simpler to understand.

Comment: I'd not seen Arel before, looking at the github page now.  https://github.com/rails/arel  Looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
School.find_by_sql("Select * from schools where id not in (select distinct(lisensable_id) from licenses where licensable_type='school' and licenses.start_date > #{Time.now} and licenses.end_date < #{Time.now})")
```

Comment: This would return only schools that *don't* have a license.  In this instance i want schools that don't have a valid license (based on start_date and end_date): schools might have more than one license, some of which may be valid and some not.

Comment: Add the condition to the inner query. Edited

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very satisfactory (i'd really like to know how to do it with just sql) but i ended up caching (with memcache) the ids of all schools that *do* have a valid license, and then just testing whether the school's id is in that list.

Like i say i'd still like to see a pure sql solution, particularly one that didn't involve more nested queries.  Got a feeling i could do it with COALESCE() but haven't quite been able to figure it out.

Comment: The only pure SQL condition that satisfies your requirements would either involve a LEFT JOIN or calling EXISTS on a correlated subquery - I demonstrated both of these approaches in their 'Rails/Arel' form above.  Sorry, but COALESCE will not help you here.

Comment: Thanks for your input @PinnyM.  I've decided not to start using Arel in my app.  It does remind me of Sequel which i've used as an alternative to ActiveRecord in other non-rails ruby apps.

Comment: ActiveRecord uses Arel under the hood to perform its magic.  Sequel is an alternative DSL that also uses Arel under the hood.  If you aren't comfortable with it, then I would suggest writing the SQL by hand and use `find_by_sql`.